# Is a relation between A and B the same as a mapping from elements of A to subsets of B?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, definition

The way I always saw it was that a relation is a subset of $A \times B$, or a collection of ordered pairs $(a,b)$, where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Is there any meaningful distinction between the two definitions?

If they are one and the same, I think my trouble lies in the definition of "mapping", and any insight you can give would be great.

The reason I ask this question is because this is how it's defined in my discrete mathematics class.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The reason you ask what? Make your question's body self contained please.

Comment: Eh... I guess you could say that.  A mapping must be well defined (have a single output), which if you take the output to be the collection of all things the input is related to is satisfied, and it must be everywhere defined (always have an output) which if the input is not related to anything can have $\emptyset$ as the output.  I never personally think of it this way, but one could describe it as such if they so choose.  I think this may muddy the interpretations of common properties of interesting relations however such as transitivity, symmetry, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you have any subset $R$ of $A\times B$, then the sections, or cuts, on $A$ define subsets of $B$: $$R_a=\{b\mid (a,b)\in R\}$$

And it is exactly the case that $R=\bigcup_{a\in A}(\{a\}\times R_a)$, almost trivially. You just need to verify that $a\mapsto R_a$ is a well-defined function, but that is just a consequence of it having a specific definition as a set.

It is also quite easy to see that the "sections function" mapping $R$ to $a\mapsto R_a$ is in fact a bijection. Between the relations between $A$ and $B$ and functions from $A$ to $\mathcal P(B)$.